# Worklight 6.2 - Push notification only for one device of two devices, registered with the same userId

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an hybrid application developed with IBM Worklight 6.2 that receives push notification. This application use the username of user as userId to register to the push notification providers.

If the user is logged in two different devices, is there a way to decide to send a push notification only for one of them?

Regards,
Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In fact you can choose one of the two:

a) Submit a notification to a specified user and a specified device. Use [WL.Server.notifyDevice](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html%23notifyDevice)  API

b) Submit a notification to the specified device of a subscribed user. Use [WL.Server.notifyDeviceSubscription](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html%23notifyDeviceSubscription) API

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!